# Object Oriented Programming, is it more object oriented to pass parameters to a method than in the constructor?

Tags: java, oop, interface

This is a general style question, which is best practice?  Which is more testable?   Let's say you have class:

```
public class MyExecutor {
   public MyExecutor(Model model) {
       this.model = model
   }
   public void execute() {
     // Do something with model;
   }

   public String toString() {
     return model.toString();
   }
}
```

With the code above, let's say I pass my object of interest in the constructor and then later use that object in the sole method.  Compare the code above to the code below.

```
public class MyExecutor implements TheExecutor {
   public MyExecutor() {
   }
   @Override
   public void execute(Model model) {
     // Do something with model;
   }   
}
```

One advantage with this code, I can define an interface method and I can define the required arguments.  Not with the constructor oriented approach.

With these approaches and there is only one constructor and one method, which approach do you prefer and why?

Comment: That depends on the goal you need to achieve.

Comment: I would go with the second, with one instance of `MyExecutor` you can execute multiple instances of `Model` one at a time. Also it's quite obvious that `Model` is not a part of `MyExecutor`'s the state.

Comment: it mainly depends if you need _immutable objects_: take a look http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29

Answer (score 4):

You have to think of the state of the object (that is what objects are, a state with ways to modify the state). If the state of the object is determined by the model, it should be in the constructor. Otherwise it should be used as a parameter that can possibly modify the state or use the state to determine the output/return value.

This is similar to the interface question. Can a `TheExecutor` only be run with a `Model`? If it needs a `Model` then it should be in the parameter list or if the objects state depends on the `Model` and execute can only be run with a `Model`, then `TheExecutor` should be an `abstract class` that holds the `Model` and each subclasses constructor should call `super( model )`.

Comment: So really the two approaches above are completely separate.  There are scenarios where you want to use approach 1 and some where you want to use approach 2.

Comment: Here is another question, some other programming languages like Common Lisp use a slot based approach for OOP.    That approach may look like  approach2 in my example above.  Does MyExector really have to have 'state'?

Comment: @BerlinBrown No, it doesn't have to have a state, but if it doesn't it sounds more like a static class. That is of course unless you want to have other classes inherit from it.

Comment: That is true, it could be thought of as a static class.  But isn't arbitrary whether that object keeps state or doesn't?